# Parameters set through the canvasApp in VF page not recieved in the connectedApp's client code

Tags: visualforce, oauth2, canvas, connected-apps

I am new to Canvas framework and stuck with some basic requirement
I have created a connected app to integrate my application with salesforce through oauth flow. callback url destination is the servlet which on invocation intially  goes through oauth protocol to recieve the access token. Access Method in the connected App is OAuth Webflow(GET) and not the Signed Request(POST).

Now one of the custom actions, say 'create' is tied with its VF page which has call to connected app as below.
<
apex:canvasApp applicationName="sampleConnectedApp"
 parameters={redirect_url:'/xyz/a=a&b=b&c=c'}"
/>

There is also a lifecycle class tied to connected app, which has onRender implentation.

```
public void onRender(Canvas.RenderContext renderContext) {
        Canvas.ApplicationContext app = renderContext.getApplicationContext();
        Canvas.EnvironmentContext env = renderContext.getEnvironmentContext();         
        URL url = new URL(app.getCanvasUrl());

    Map<String, Object> params = (Map<String, Object>)
      JSON.deserializeUntyped(env.getParametersAsJSON());        
    String urlEncodedEndpoint = EncodingUtil.urlEncode((String)params.get('redirect_url'), 'UTF-8');
    String queryParams = '?redirect_url='+urlEncodedEndpoint;
    //System.debug('Controller finalURL: ' + url.getPath()+queryParams );
    app.setCanvasUrlPath(url.getPath()+queryParams );

}
```

now on clicking create action invokes the client app. In clientservlet i have request.getParameter("redirect_url"); but this doesn't give me entire url, the value here is /xyz/?a=a.

new parameter(previousParams.put('newCustomParam','newValue');) set in the onRender method too not recieved at client side. Also how to read the entityFields set that is added to envContext in clientside code.